# Why jstatd has no response?

Tags: java

I am trying to start jstatd on linux. here is what I did.

1) create the file `jstatd.all.policy`

```
grant codebase "file:/home/ailiu/jdk1.6.0_24/lib/tools.jar" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

2)  made sure the `tools.jar` exists at the specific path
 `/home/ailiu/jdk1.6.0_24/lib/tools.jar`

3) run jstatd as

```
./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy
```

the execution simply hangs, no response at all.

I've tried with JDK 1.7 and 1.6, all the same.

4) jps can see the process of jstatd, along with other java programs.

any help? thanks a lot.

Comment: Try running jstatd as `./jstatd -J-Djava.security.policy=jstatd.all.policy &`

Answer (score 0):

`jstatd` does exactly what it ought to do: it’s a daemon intended to run in the background. It will run waiting for network requests until killed. What did you expect?

`jps` can show local java processes without the `jstatd`. You can try whether the `jstatd` runs by using `jps hostname` where hostname should not be `localhost`, i.e. it should be a network-visible name of the machine where `jstatd` runs.

Comment: thanks for reply, Holger. however, from another question thread, it is said, "Output would be something like below :-
[1] 12195". If there is no output (as what I see), then how to tell which port is used for RMI registry?

Comment: If you don’t specify a port of you own, a standard port will be used. You don’t have to care about it as all tools will use that standard port if you don’t specify your own. But for completeness: the default port number is `1099`

Comment: thanks again, Holger. However, I tried jstat with the default port 1099, which doesn't work. And, I still expect jstatd returns a port number, even it is default number. And it should not hang there. Deamon program can run in background, but not necessary to hang. right?